# How to not increment algorithm numbers when using \againframe in beamer

Tags: beamer, numbering, algorithms

As is known, algorithms and equations in latex are automatically numbered. When using `\againframe` though, incrementing such number is undesired. How to avoid this? (I still want numbering, but it will not change during each `\againframe` invocation).

A minimal working example is following. As can be seen, on second frame, the algorithm shows up with index number `2`, rather than `1`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\floatname{algorithm}{Procedure}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\begin{document}

\frame<1>[label=myframe] 
{
 \begin{algorithm}[H] 
 \caption{foobar()}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]  
\alt<1>
{ \STATE run() }
{ \STATE \textbf{run()} }
 \end{algorithmic} 
 \end{algorithm}
}

\againframe<2>{myframe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating a case in which using `\againframe` increases the equation numbering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To correct for the wrong algorithm number in your example, simply add

```
\addtocounter{algorithm}{-1}
```

just before calling `\againframe<2>{myframe}`. This is what the 2-slide output looks like - producing the same counter for each procedure:

[image: Beamer presentation]

However, in a more complicated setting where other algorithms are used in between the algorithm that is displayed again using `\againframe`, you could store the original counter. Here's a mockup of what this might involve:

```
\newcounter{storealgcounter}% Temporary storage for algorithm counter
\newcounter{algfoobar}% Holds the algorithm counter for algorithm 'foobar'
\setcounter{algfoobar}{\value{algorithm}}% Store algorithm 'foobar' counter

\frame<1>[label=myframe]{%
  \begin{algorithm}[H] 
  \caption{foobar()}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]  
    \alt<1>
      { \STATE run() }
      { \STATE \textbf{run()} }
  \end{algorithmic} 
  \end{algorithm}
}

\frame
... % some frames with algorithms
\frame

\setcounter{storealgcounter}{\value{algorithm}}% Temporarily store algorithm counter
\setcounter{algorithm}{\value{algfoobar}}% Recall algorithm 'foobar' counter
\againframe<2>{myframe}
\setcounter{algorithm}{\value{storealgcounter}}% Restore algorithm counter
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight modification of Werner's solution where — except for two counter definitions in the preamble — the changes are localized in the initial frame (so if you have more than one `\againframe` you don't have to repeat the whole set of commands). I've added two additional frames with theorems which demonstrate the continued numbering. All the mechanics is concentrated in the first frame (the one to be shown again).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\floatname{algorithm}{Procedure}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\newcounter{inialg}
\newcounter{savealg}

\begin{document}

\frame<1>[label=myframe] 
{
  \alt<1>{\setcounter{inialg}{\value{algorithm}}}{%
    \setcounter{savealg}{\value{algorithm}}%
    \setcounter{algorithm}{\value{inialg}}%
  }
  \begin{algorithm}[H] 
    \caption{foobar()}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]  
      \alt<1>
      { \STATE run() }
      { \STATE \textbf{run()} }
    \end{algorithmic} 
  \end{algorithm}
  \only<2->{\setcounter{algorithm}{\value{savealg}}}
}

\frame
{
  Another algorithm in between.
  \begin{algorithm}[H] 
    \caption{havefun()}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]  
      \STATE enjoy()
    \end{algorithmic} 
  \end{algorithm}
}

\againframe<2>{myframe}

\frame
{
  Yet another algorithm.
  \begin{algorithm}[H] 
    \caption{relax()}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]  
      \STATE sleep()
    \end{algorithmic} 
  \end{algorithm}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\resetcounteronoverlays{algorithm}` to add the counter to the list of counters which get reset for every overlay:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}

\floatname{algorithm}{Procedure}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\resetcounteronoverlays{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<1>[label=myframe] 
 \begin{algorithm}[H] 
 \caption{foobar()}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]  
\alt<1>
{ \STATE run() }
{ \STATE \textbf{run()} }
 \end{algorithmic} 
 \end{algorithm}
\end{frame}

\againframe<2>{myframe}

\end{document}
```